# Normal curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm working on a problem but I don't understand some parts to. I get why $|\sin \theta|= |N_1 \times N_2|$ but why does $|N_1 \times N_2|= |n \times (N_1 \times N_2)|$. Is there a formula do this that I'm not aware of that lets this happen?

http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/weiyi_zhang/example4_sol.pdf refer to problem 3.

Comment: That equation is true if $n$ is unit and $n, N_1,$ and $N_2$ are coplanar.

Comment: Perhaps superficial , but: $$\left(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}\right) \times\mathbf{C} =\left(\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{C}\right)\mathbf{B}-\left(\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{C}\right)\mathbf{A}$$ Vector triple product ,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever $v$ and $u$ are orthogonal, $\lVert v \times u \rVert = \lVert v \rVert \lVert u \rVert$; this is a (very) special case of the first formula you mention. Since $\lVert n \rVert = 1$, we're done if we use this formula with $v = n$ and $u = N_1 \times N_2$; at least if we can show that $n$ is orthogonal to $N_1 \times N_2$ so let's do that: If $\gamma$ is a unit speed parametrization of $C$, then $\gamma' \cdot N_1 = \gamma' \cdot N_2 = 0$, so $\gamma'$ is parallel to $N_1 \times N_2$. Now, since $\gamma' \cdot \gamma'' = 0$, you have $\gamma'' \cdot (N_1 \times N_2) = 0$, and therefore also that $n \cdot (N_1 \times N_2) = 0$.

**Edit (answer for the comment below)**: What you write becomes a bit confusing as you can't multiply vectors by that (you need to put in some inner products where relevant). I would put it as follows (and let me just take all of it at once): Since you know that $k_1 = \gamma'' \cdot N_1 = k n \cdot N_1$ and $k_2 = \gamma'' \cdot N_2 = kn \cdot N_2$, you find that
$$k_1 N_2 - k_2 N_1 = (kn \cdot N_1)N_2 - (kn \cdot N_2)N_1 = k (N_1 \times N_2) \times n,$$
by the triple product formula (so far, so good). Now, taking norm squares on both sides here and reading from right to left, we find that
$$k^2 \lVert (N_1 \times N_2) \times n \rVert^2 = \langle k_1 N_2 - k_2 N_1 , k_1 N_2 - k_2 N_1 \rangle = k_1^2 + k_2^2 - 2k_1k_2 \langle N_1,N_2 \rangle.$$
Before, we argued that the left hand side is exactly $k^2 \sin^2 \theta$, and of course $\langle N_1 , N_2 \rangle = \cos \theta$. I think this is what you're trying to say as well, but make sure to always indicate that you're taking dot products/inner products where relevant (and note also that there's not really any reason to take square roots; it's typically a lot easier not to).

Comment: In fact, $\|v \times u \|$ = $\|v\|\|u\| \sin \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $v$ and $u$ so that's where the last equality comes from also.

Comment: Yeah, it's also where the first equality in OP's question comes from, so I figured I would just refer to that.

Comment: Oh ok so because $|n|=1$ and is perpendicular we can change it to a vector product

Comment: I also had another question. Idk if you saw the link but I'm a little confused in the beginning. I did this, $|\lambda_1 - \lambda_2| = |(n\cdot N_1k)N_2 - (n \cdot N_2k)N_1|$
$=\sqrt{((n\cdot N_1k)N_2 - (n \cdot N_2k)N_1)^2}$
$=\sqrt{\lambda^2_1 + \lambda^2_2 - 2\lambda_1\lambda_2N_1N_2} $

$= \sqrt{\lambda^2_1 + \lambda^2_2 - 2\lambda_1\lambda_2 \cos \theta}$. Is this how the $k$ gets cancelled. In the problem he pulls the $k$, is what I did the same thing? Or is it there to show that $k$ is a multiple of $|\sin \theta|$?

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Ok so i'm still a bit confused. So your using $k_1$ and $k_2$ instead of $\lambda$?

Comment: ok I do understand how you set it up, but the only thing now is why does the $k^2$ disappear? How does it get cancelled when you set up the dot product part. I just don't see how it becomes that vector you got

Comment: Oh nvm I just did the mah and got it. Thank you so much it was really helpful :)